# create mongo connection handler with python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, handler, database

how to write mongo connection handler with pymongo?
I want to one connection to mongo for all module in my program.
I mean use of instance for pymongo MongoClient and write handler for it.

Answer (score 2):

Create a [`MongoClient`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient) instance somewhere in your application, like in an `__init__.py` and then import that object to wherever you need to use it. The client implements connection pooling so you should be fine without writing an extra handler.

Example:

```
app/__init__.py

db = MongoClient()
```

and then

```
app/module.py
from app import db
```

Comment: I want create connection pool, and handle all query in one class and i n all module use of my handler or create instance of handler for all.

Comment: But *why* would you want to do that when `MongoClient()` provides that  functionality?